# How to parameterise the timeUnit in Vega-Lite?

Tags: parameters, bar-chart, vega-lite

I have created a simple bar chart that shows counts per time period.  In the next step I want to make the time period configurable.  I have added a `params` block and defined parameter `aggWindow`.  This adds a select box to the chart.

How should I propagate the selected value of the parameter so that it gets reflected in the chart? I was hoping changing

```json
  "timeUnit": "date"
```

to

```
  "timeUnit" : {"param": "aggWindow"}
```

would do the trick but this syntax appears illegal.

Here is [a link to the chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289JQOKQAdxrL6aACwAGa0vg0yWNAGZbSnEmXKassmjElZSRMFFRQYiRBBjU0AG1QNhw4WThlNBAAJmtMgEZ+a3zczIACXNzUcsrMkABfBUTk1PT0bLyCopcyiqqcuoaQJJS0jLb8wv5cyxLCyoqxS37G4ZasnPHMydLZqpdF+uXm0fWCzdyADhnMudQ+g8GmkdaTnP5M7ZdUFx7rJYeV47tawuAoAdhmli+Yi+NXuQyOzyBILy3S+832A3hTzWSLepV2ADZUO8-ljVmMCsiAJwzCouaFiWEAXXqIE86iQCAg8VAsk5cAySDIZAA6r5lGxjEZItEBehgpgBUomOK0Lz+RkACo0BBwErJTRsZQlIy+HAMTAZCBwQRwKCWpRJHRybmoOIgBByegKpUqEK+4xwOAAayMntkFhZtSZSmQ6lD6CYSHURhSUCNvn84RAAA81SAAGY0G2rMlGTAAT2SGUVCBwbA5gnLOrgAFVZHQMj7+iAK-mhWR1HxFRl0wwI+Wq3KQABHBhICN0EI0Uh1Wq1IA).

A similar example is available [here](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/time-units/) but it uses Vega, not Vega-lite.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to transform the date field using [timeUnitSpecifier](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#timeUnitSpecifier) and used it as a nominal field for x-axis, this seems to convert and use my timeunits properly from params. I didn't find any `expr` which will support the timeUnit config. But my example is not temporal, so there won't be any continuous axis.

Below is the config or refer the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289JQOKQAdxrL6aACwAGa0vg0yWNAGZbSnEmXKassmjElZSRMFFRQYiRBBjU0AG1QNhw4WThlNBAAJmtMgEZ+a3zczIACXNzUcsrMkABfBUTk1PT0bLyCopcyiqqcuoaQJJS0jLb8wv5cyxLCyoqxS37G4ZasnPHMydLZqpdF+uXm0fWCzdyADhnMudQ+g8GmkdaTnP5M7ZdUFx7rJYeV47tawuAoAdhmli+Yi+NXuQyOzyBILy3S+832A3hTzWSLepV2ADZUO8-ljVmMCsiAJwzCouaFiWEAXXqIE86iQCAg8VAsk5cAySDIZAA6r5lGxjEZItEBehgpgBUomOK0Lz+RkACo0BBwErJTRsZQlIy+HAMTAZCBwQRwKCWpRJHRybmoOJxEAIOQWIIhAVM32KozGOBwADWRi9sgsLNqAZAmA5sggADM2OoEDyQFAolAGII-RkdLqAGLp5CYAAUxbglYVDAQlDJAEoFCUawBVWR0ADKySgNBTNDg6krQtF4slzebRiQruzclI6kVygAIoW40pkOoI+gmEh1EYUlAjb5-OEQAAPNUgIc21Yn2RLlfroNKTAAT2SGVkbAQviifoQA-G9x3UPgg3QE8GGjIxP2-dAAEcGCQaM6BCGhSDqWpaiAA) sample:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "...",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 300,
  "padding": 5,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"opened": "2021-01-12 11:11:12"},
      {"opened": "2021-01-13 11:11:02"},
      {"opened": "2021-01-14 01:11:54"},
      {"opened": "2021-02-12 01:11:34"},
      {"opened": "2021-02-18 02:11:02"},
      {"opened": "2021-02-22 03:31:10"},
      {"opened": "2021-03-07 04:35:32"},
      {"opened": "2021-03-21 11:31:54"},
      {"opened": "2021-03-22 11:36:22"},
      {"opened": "2021-03-29 01:35:52"}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "aggWindow",
      "value": "date",
      "bind": {
        "name": "Time period ",
        "input": "select",
        "options": [["month","date"], "date", "week", "month"]
      }
    }
  ],
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "timeFormat(time(datum.opened), timeUnitSpecifier(aggWindow))",
      "as": "convertedDate"
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "convertedDate", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {"aggregate": "count", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Trying `transform` sounds like a good hint; I had been poking around `endcoding.scales` but did not get far. Also, if I look into **Compiled Vega** tab (in the Vega Editor) in my example linked from the question I can see that several transforms have been generated.

Comment: In the end I was not able to find a satisfactory solution in Vega-lite and have built the chart with Vega.  While the specification is longer, I also found it easier to work with. The primitives are simpler and easier to grasp with less magic going on behind the scenes.